# MATLAB testing framework

Tags: testing, matlab

I am using MATLAB R2008a, what testing framework is available and what is recommended.
the need for comprehensive from having to refactor a 5 kloc matlab application to Matlab oop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several listed on the [c2 wiki](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestingFramework).  [xUnit](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846) and [mlunit_2008a](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21888) seem to be the most highly regarded.

Comment: In addition, the documentation for xUnit seems to be very good.

Answer (score 9):

You can try MATLAB xUnit, which you can download from the [MATLAB Central File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846).

Comment: I tried it, but it couldn't find my tests. Using Matlab R2008b 7.7 and Windows 7

Comment: The most likely explanation for what you are seeing is some problem in the test files. Can you post a sample test file so I can look at it?  See also my answer to the question you posted about this.

Answer (score 2):

Note:  current versions of Matlab (2013a and later) have integrated xUnit directly into Matlab.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html