# Unit-testing framework for MATLAB

Tags: unit-testing, matlab

What are the unit-testing frameworks for MATLAB out there, and how do they compare? How should I choose one for our project? What are their pros and cons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB testing framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417327/matlab-testing-framework)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the most popular framework for MATLAB is [xUnit Test Framework](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework) available on File Exchange. Very flexible and well documented.

Some other unit-testing tools are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#MATLAB) and [here](http://mlunit.dohmke.de/Unit_Testing_With_Matlab).

Another very recent and interesting File Exchange submission is [Doctest](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28862-doctest-embed-testable-examples-in-your-functions-help-comments). Not exactly unit-testing framework though, it works like *doctest* in Python. I haven't tried it yet, but looks very promising for simple tests embedded into function's help.

Comment: »As of R2013a (March 2013), MATLAB includes a unit test framework. There are no plans to continue further development of MATLAB xUnit.«

Answer (score 20):

The **R2013a** release of MATLAB includes a fully featured [*unit test framework*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html)

Answer (score 2):

mUnit does the trick:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11306-munit-a-unit-testing-framework-in-matlab

I've been using it for >2 years. I had to do some adaptations, such as printing hyperlinks in matlab command window instead of simple text (To quickly go where the error happened).
Nevertheless, it is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

[mlUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mlunit/). As far as I know, the only MATLAB unit test framework that:

- outputs jUnit XML reports
- comes with an [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) target to execute MATLAB and your unit tests out of the box
- with these benefits, lets you easily execute your unit tests in a [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) system, e.g. [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), and [monitor your test results](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+graph) there.

Also, mlUnit works on older MATLAB versions, e.g. R2006b and probably older. You define your test cases in test suites. A test suite is a MATLAB function file, a test case is a subfunction in that file.

Use the newest 1.6.x version. The 2.0 beta migrated an older version to MATLAB's classdef for implementation, but has not been maintained since. If you run into problems, there's an issue tracking system, because mlUnit is maintained at sourceforge.net.