# Is it possible to set matlab to validate reachable functions before running

Tags: matlab, validation, syntax-error

## Background

I am used to strongly typed, compiled languages so I'm used to misspellings being pretty much instantly picked up as undeclared variables.

However since Matlab is a weakly typed language this doesn't happen automatically and my development cycle tends to be:

```
write function(s)
|
˅
Run  <-------------------------
|                             |
˅                             |
Crash due to misspelling/typo |
|                             |
˅                             |
Correct typo -----------------|
```

The run process can run for several minutes before getting to the typo, which slows down my development cycle considerably.
I'm using matlab version 2007b

## Question

Is there any way to validate a function such that the use of non-existent variables etc are picked up without having to run the whole program? Given that each function has its own variable space it feels like this should be possible.

I am aware that is it possible to get a list of dependencies using [depfun](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/depfun.html) however I've not been able to find any way to validate those functions.

For example the following function will always fail but produces no warnings until it is run

```
function [biggest]=getBiggest(variableName1, variableName2)
    if variablename1>variableName2, %<---misspelling!
        biggest=variableName1;
    else
        biggest=variableName2;
    end
end
```

Comment: Note that my answer is based on newer versions of matlab, though I believe the option was already available in 2007b. Otherwise consider updating, 2007 is already some time ago.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin If only it was my decision

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you are either using a different editor, or that you changed your warning preferences.

When going to `home > preferences > code analyzer` make sure you have the one enabled that contains something like:

> cannot determine whether ... is a variable or a function

Comment: This leads to a warning appearing in the text editor (although for me it was mlint options) and is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Although oddly this warning now triggers for all functions, even those in the same m file

Comment: @RichardTingle Make sure you are not using them via `eval` or so. If you think the code is fine, I would recommend making a minimal example and asking a separate question.

Comment: I have created annother question regarding that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554924/m-lint-cannot-decide-whether-name-is-a-variable-or-a-function-and-assumes-it)

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB Linter will generally pick up variables that are used before being assigned (e.g. because it's a typo), but it isn't perfect. It is enabled by default (in R2011b, at least) in the GUI but can also be run outside of MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlint.html

Comment: Hmm, mlint seems to pick up on variables that are never used (which usually have warnings in the text editor as well) but `mlint('getBiggest.m')` doesn't object to the mispelled `variablename1`

Comment: You're correct by default, I just realized I have two extra messages turned on for it:
"Code Analyzer cannot determine whether <name> is a variable or a function, and assumes it is a function." and "Variable <name> is used, but might be unset (within a script)."

Those should pick up a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The [Code Analyzer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-code-analyzer-report.html?s_tid=doc_12b#f9-12181) should catch most things like that.

Comment: The instructions for that bring up the mlint code check report but no code analyser. Perhaps this is simpy unavailable for my version of matlab

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would create some unit tests. I use [xUnit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework), but there is a whole question dedicated to it: [Unit-testing framework for MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992295/unit-testing-framework-for-matlab).

For sure it will catch syntax errors. In addition it helps checking the algorithm.