# 'M-Lint cannot decide whether <name> is a variable or a function and assumes it is a function' warning generated for all functions

Tags: matlab, warnings, mlint

### Background

I have recently turned on the M-Lint warning 'M-Lint cannot decide whether ... is a variable or a function and assumes it is a function' as per [Is it possible to set matlab to validate reachable functions before running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553530/is-it-possible-to-set-matlab-to-validate-reachable-functions-before-running/21553765?noredirect=1#comment32551844_21553765) in order to try to detect misspelled variable names.

M-Lint was renamed to code analyser in recent versions of matlab but I am using Matlab2007b.

### Question

All functions seem to be generating this warning, even those in the same m-file. For example in the below code `needlessDelegate` generates this warning when used.

Is it possible to avoid this warning for valid functions? Or are my functions in some way incorrectly written?

```
function [biggest]=getBiggest(variable1, variable2)
    biggest=needlessDelegate(variable1, variable2); %<-- needlessDelegate generates warning. 'M-Lint cannot decide whether <name> is a variable or a function and assumes it is a function' 
end

function [biggest]=needlessDelegate(variable1, variable2)
    if variable1>variable2,
        biggest=variable1;
    else
        biggest=variable2;
    end
end
```

> 'M-Lint cannot decide whether 'needlessDelegate' is a variable or a function and
> assumes it is a function'

Comment: I confirm that this still happens on `2012b` and based on [this explanation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-code-for-errors-and-warnings.html?s_tid=doc_12b) I believe it should not.

Comment: Well, your delegate *is* needless.... Seems to be fixed in in R2013a+ as I don't get any warnings. Does this only happen in precisely this case? What if `needlessDelegate` was a nested function or was defined in a separate M-file?

Comment: @horchler It seems to be some in-built funtions and all same m-file functions but not the primary function in an m file accessed from a script etc.

Comment: Does the R2007b version support right-clicking on the warning and and selecting "Suppress..." > {On This Line | In This File | In All Files}?

Comment: @horchler I could certainly supress these warning, in fact I only recently turned them on. But I want the positive effects of the warning "detecting things that seem not to exist" without the "triggering all the time" effects

Comment: Well, it seems like in 2007b it's not refined so you just get a lot of false positives. You could still use turn off the warnings per line or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions are not incorrectly written. However, this MLint check is not going to do what I think (from reading your other question) you want. It's not a very useful check - that's why it's off by default.

Consider that before your line

```
biggest=needlessDelegate(variable1, variable2);
```

you could have had the command `load myData.mat`, and the .mat file could contain a variable `needlessDelegate`. So until runtime, there's no way for MLint to know in general what things are functions and what things are variables.

The exception is really only when `needlessDelegate` is defined prior to its call - for example if you preceded your line with the command `needlessDelegate = @(x,y) x+y;`. You'll see then that the MLint message disappears.

As you can see, it's not a very useful check in general, which is why it's off by default.

Perhaps this example also gives an answer to your other question too - MATLAB is not able to have any idea of which things might be misspellings, or undefined variables, as you can just 'poof' things into existence at any time using `load`, which can't be examined before runtime.

Comment: Hmm, this does not help my daily rage against matlab. Regardless thank you for your answer and it does make sense; I am trying to recreate my familiar statically typed environment (with all its nice checks) within a dynamically typed environment which was never likely to go well. I shall turn this warning back off and try to improve my spelling

Comment: When the rage comes, just remember that the (run->find error->fix) cycle is quicker than the (compile->run->find error->fix) cycle, even if there are a few more errors due to less strict typing.

Comment: Ah you see the problem is I've come from Java where any decent IDE is compiling continuously, there is no (visible) compile step, but the second you make a mistake you get a red underline telling you that that line is wrong. I've been spoilt by that unfortunately